# the_posts_navigation is not working

Tags: pagination, navigation

Unfortunately, `the_posts_navigation()` function is not working for me. When I click on 'Older Posts' it's showing '404 page  I don't know why my code is not working.

Here is the code -

```
<div class="row">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
    <div class="col-md-3 thumbnailu">
        <a class="thmb" href="<?php echo get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'link_name', true); ?>" target="_blank">
        <?php 
        the_post_thumbnail( 'website-image-size', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); 
    ?>

        <p class="caption"><?php the_title(); ?><br> 
        by <?php echo get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'author_name', true); ?> </p>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php the_posts_navigation(array(
    'prev_text' => 'Older Posts',
    'next_text' => 'Newer Posts',
    'screen_reader_text' => ' ',
));
?>
```

It's showing the same error even I use the `previous_posts_link()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This function uses `get_the_posts_pagination()` which uses the GLOBAL `$wp_query` to setup the `paginate_links()` function, so I believe that doesn't work for `get_posts`.

Try use the function `paginate_links()` by itself or the function `posts_nav_link()`

Answer (score -1):

Place `the_posts_navigation`inside while loop hopefully it works!!

Comment: Could you explain why should it help? It doesn’t make much sense for me...